# Any idea how to solve this "Value Error".python 3.9.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, valueerror

[image: I mean how solve this error.]

Here is the code and I couldn't figure out what to do.

```
import winapps
import os
import subprocess
name=input("Enter AppName: ")
for app in winapps.search_installed(name):
  print(app)
input()
```

**Any idea how to solve this??**

Comment: Deal is your format is %d%m%Y but it needs an %Y%m%d

Comment: @Ata Reenes,  And how to do that.?